# ADT - libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: kali-linux

i installed android sdk on kali linux rolling, when i run adb it show me an error like below

```
 /home/usr/share/android-sdk/platform-tool/aapt:

error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you missing some libs,
install them:

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

worked for me on ubuntu.